# Fixnum is deprecated - when I run rake db: seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fixnum

In my project whenever I run the `rake db:seed` command I get these messages

[image]

How could I solve those warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ruby version 2.4.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/roo/versions/2.8.3) (~Dec 2016) unified `Fixnum` and `Bignum` into `Integer` and deprecated `Fixnum`. You're probably using ruby version 2.4.0 or later. Your version 1.13.2 of the `roo` gem is older than that (~Dec 2013) and is using `Fixnum`. Thus you get the warning.

Your code will still run fine for now with the warning, but if you want to get rid of it, you could upgrade your `roo` gem. The [latest version is 2.8.3](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/) (Feb 2020). If you do upgrade, you may have some code changes to do depending upon what may have changed in the newer version of the gem.